# What is the MathNet equivalent of numpy array[0,:] *= 1.23

Tags: c#, python, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I have to port some python (numpy) code in c# (MathNet).
I can write in python:

```
mtx = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])
mtx[0,:] *= 1.23    #multiply all elements in row 0 by 1.23
```

How can I do this in MathNet? Is there better (faster) solution than:

```cs
 Matrix<double> mtx = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(2,3);
 //...
 for(int i = 0; i < mtx.ColumnCount; i++)
    mtx[0,i] *= 1.23;
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways, for sure cleaner than `for`.
Starting with matrix full of `1`.

```
 Matrix<double> mtx = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(2, 3, 1);
 
 mtx.SetRow(0, mtx.Row(0).Multiply(1.23));

 Console.WriteLine(mtx);
```

returns

> DenseMatrix 2x3-Double
>
> 1,23  1,23  1,23
>
> 1     1     1

Answer (score 5):

For completeness: Math.NET Numerics itself actually does support a notation which is somewhat close to your NumPy example. C# does not support it, but other more powerful .Net languages like F# do:

```
let mtx = matrix [[0.;1.;2.];[3.;4.;5.]]
mtx.[0,*] <- 1.23 * mtx.[0,*]
```

Comment: Do you think, if I have to use the library often and more intensively , I should prefer the F# language?

Comment: @ThWin, I think, yes.